# R - Create a new date column based on current date column if it matches with other column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below on users campaign with below details:

Columns are: **email_address, response_date, campaign_name, state, suburb, postcode, magazine_subs_title, response_type**

```
 email_address  response_date   campaign_name   state   suburb  postcode    magazine_subs_title response_type
jow.wow@gmail.com 1/02/2018 18:01   2018_Beauty_Acq NSW Sydney  2000    AGL opened
dew.jones@yahoo.id 03/10/2017  14:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane    4000    MHI delivered
dew.jones@yahoo.id 03/10/2017  17:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane    4000    MHI opened
jow.wow@gmail.com 25/01/2018 9:00 2018_Beauty_Acq   NSW Sydney  2000    AGL delivered
jow.wow@gmail.com 14/07/2017 11:00  2017_Fashion_Show   NSW Sydney  2000    AGL delivered
```

From here, I want to extract the response_date where response_type = 'delivered' and specific for each campaigns and end up with below table:

```
email_address   response_date   campaign_name   state   suburb  postcode    magazine_subs_title response_type   delivered_date
jow.wow@gmail.com   1/02/2018 18:01 2018_Beauty_Acq NSW Sydney  2000    AGL opened  25/01/2018 9:00
dew.jones@yahoo.id  03/10/2017  14:00:00 PM 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane    4000    MHI delivered   03/10/2017  14:00:00 PM
dew.jones@yahoo.id  03/10/2017  17:00:00 PM 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane    4000    MHI opened  03/10/2017  14:00:00 PM
jow.wow@gmail.com   25/01/2018 9:00 2018_Beauty_Acq NSW Sydney  2000    AGL delivered   25/01/2018 9:00
jow.wow@gmail.com   14/07/2017 11:00    2017_Fashion_Show   NSW Sydney  2000    AGL delivered   14/07/2017 11:00
```

Does that makes sense?

Any one know how to perform that sort of operation in R? 
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy over the earliest value from the `response_date` column (grouped by `campaign_name`) to a new column called `delivered_date`? Have you tried anything?  Can you post some sample code so we can better help you?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, yeah my solution wasnt up to scratch and its creating more rows of data. It was wayyy too ugly.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be using `lubridate`, `tidyr` and `dplyr` .

The approach is to first prepare data. Read `response_date` and `Time` separately and then `unite` those to column to make `response_date`. Then use `parse_date_time` to convert those two columns in to datetime format which is optional(as OP is not taking any decision on this date). Finally apply `ifelse` to populate `delivered_date`.

```
#Data

df <- read.table(text = "
email_address  response_date Time  campaign_name   state   suburb  postcode    magazine_subs_title response_type
jow.wow@gmail.com 1/02/2018 18:01   2018_Beauty_Acq NSW Sydney  2000    AGL opened
dew.jones@yahoo.id 03/10/2017  14:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane    4000    MHI delivered
dew.jones@yahoo.id 03/10/2017  17:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane    4000    MHI opened
jow.wow@gmail.com 25/01/2018 9:00 2018_Beauty_Acq   NSW Sydney  2000    AGL delivered
jow.wow@gmail.com 14/07/2017 11:00  2017_Fashion_Show   NSW Sydney  2000    AGL delivered", header=T, stringsAsFactor = F)

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   unite("response_date", c("response_date", "Time"), sep= " ") %>%
   mutate(response_date = parse_date_time(response_date, c("dmy HMS", "dmy HM"))) %>%
   mutate(delivered_date = ifelse(grepl("delivered",response_type), as.character(response_date), NA)) %>%
  group_by(campaign_name, state, suburb, postcode) %>% 
  fill(delivered_date) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  as.data.frame()    
Result:
   email_address       response_date     campaign_name state   suburb postcode magazine_subs_title response_type      delivered_date
#1  jow.wow@gmail.com 2017-07-14 11:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   NSW   Sydney     2000                 AGL     delivered 2017-07-14 11:00:00
#2 dew.jones@yahoo.id 2017-10-03 14:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane     4000                 MHI     delivered 2017-10-03 14:00:00
#3 dew.jones@yahoo.id 2017-10-03 17:00:00 2017_Fashion_Show   QLD Brisbane     4000                 MHI        opened 2017-10-03 14:00:00
#4  jow.wow@gmail.com 2018-02-01 18:01:00   2018_Beauty_Acq   NSW   Sydney     2000                 AGL        opened                <NA>
#5  jow.wow@gmail.com 2018-01-25 09:00:00   2018_Beauty_Acq   NSW   Sydney     2000                 AGL     delivered 2018-01-25 09:00:00
```

Comment: Hi @MKR, the original response_date was actually date & time in one column but yeah, I can definitely use parse_date_time although I used Posixct instead to do this.

Comment: Also, on the above, its just filling up the delivered_date for response_type "delivered", what I was looking for is to fill up the delivered_date for response_type = "opened".

Comment: @slaw Ah. It was not very clear in expected result because of formatting. It can be done with use of `fill` or `lag` . I'll update answer in couple of hours. Thx for pointing it out.

Comment: @slauw I have updated the answer to update `delivered_date` even for response type = `opened`. I have used `fill` to fit the purpose.